# Manually create a JUnit Result object

Tags: unit-testing, testing, junit, junit4

To execute automated UI tests, I trigger tests on [an external cloud service which requires the upload of our test suite](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-android-appium-java-junit.html) (for the purpose of this question please consider their approach a given).

I still want this process to be encapsulated into a JUnit runner to be consistent with runs utilising different cloud services or local execution. I execute my tests with Maven

```
mvn clean install -Dtest=TestRunner -Dproperties=/path/to/settings.file
```

and I want this flow to be consistent no matter which test provider is used.

The workaround I came up with is to trigger the tests like this **on my local machine**:

```
@Override
public void run(RunNotifier notifier) {
  if (someCondition) {
    new DelegateRunner().run(notifier);
  } else {
    super.run(notifier);
  }
}
```

The `DelegateRunner` then calls the third-party service which triggers the tests **on the cloud**. How can I map the results I receive from this service (I can query their API) back to my local JUnit execution?

The class `RunNotifier` offers methods like `fireTestFinished` or `fireTestFailure` but I'm not sure how to build the objects (`Result`, `Description`, `Failure`) these methods take as parameters. I suspect I need to make use of test listeners but I can't figure out the details.

In a broader sense, what are my options to create JUnit test results when the actual tests are running on a remote machine or not even being executed as JUnit tests? Is this a use-case someone has encountered before. It might be slightly exotic but I don't think I'm the first either.

For a start, I just want to provide a binary result - tests passed or at least one test failed - in a way that doesn't break any JUnit integrations (like the Maven surefire plugin).

Right now, I get:

```
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 501.287 sec
```

and

```
No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.)
```

How can I fail the build in case there is a test failure and pass it otherwise (with number of tests as 1)? I can think of a few hacky ways but I'm sure there is a proper one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At it's most basic, with a single test result, the `DelegateRunner` could be something like this:

```
public class DelegateRunner extends Runner {

    private Description testDescription = Description
            .createTestDescription("groupName", "testName");

    public DelegateRunner(Class<?> testClass) {
    }

    @Override
    public Description getDescription() {
        return testDescription;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(RunNotifier notifier) {
        notifier.fireTestStarted(testDescription);
        ... trigger remote test ...
        if (passed)
            notifier.fireTestFinished(testDescription);
        else
            notifier.fireTestFailure(new Failure(testDescription,
                    new AssertionError("Details of the failure")));
    }

}
```

Then both `getDescription()` and `run()` would need to be wrapped:

```
public class FrontRunner extends Runner {
    private Runner runner;

    public FrontRunner(Class<?> testClass) throws InitializationError {
        if (someCondition)
            runner = new DelegateRunner(testClass);
        else
            runner = new JUnit4(testClass);
    }

    @Override
    public Description getDescription() {
        return runner.getDescription();
    }

    @Override
    public void run(RunNotifier notifier) {
        runner.run(notifier);
    }
}
```

(Assuming `someCondition` can be known up front, and that it's just the default `JUnit4` runner that's needed normally).

This comes through to the Maven build as expected:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running ...FrontRunnerTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.078 sec <<< FAILURE!
testName(groupName)  Time elapsed: 0.015 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: Details of the failure
        at so.ownrunner.DelegateRunner.run(DelegateRunner.java:28)
        at so.ownrunner.FrontRunner.run(FrontRunner.java:27)
        at ...

Results :

Failed tests:   testName(groupName): Details of the failure

Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

---

Then if a more structured response is needed, `Description.addChild()` can be used to nest the suites and/or tests, e.g. :

```
public class NestedDelegateRunner extends Runner {

    private Description suiteDescription = Description
            .createSuiteDescription("groupName");
    private Description test1Description = Description
            .createTestDescription("groupName", "test1");
    private Description test2Description = Description
            .createTestDescription("groupName", "test2");

    public NestedDelegateRunner(Class<?> testClass) {
        suiteDescription.addChild(test1Description);
        suiteDescription.addChild(test2Description);
    }

    @Override
    public Description getDescription() {
        return suiteDescription;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(RunNotifier notifier) {
        notifier.fireTestStarted(test1Description);
        notifier.fireTestStarted(test2Description);

        notifier.fireTestFinished(test1Description);
        notifier.fireTestFailure(new Failure(test2Description,
                new AssertionError("Details of the failure")));
    }

}
```

In fact the `addChild()` is not crucial, but without it the structure can be less obvious - e.g. something like Eclipse will just show `Unrooted tests`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the `Unrooted tests` issue. I ran into this as well, should have included it in my original question.